# Trouble using ArgumentMatchers in Mockito using when()

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I'm writing some unit test with Mockito and I have the following situation:

```
AmazonS3 mockedS3 = Mockito.mock( AmazonS3.class )

Bucket mockBucket = Mockito.mock( Bucket.class )
Mockito.when( mockBucket.getName() ).thenReturn("bucket-1-pub")

Mockito.when(mockedS3.doesBucketExistV2("bucket-1-pub")).thenReturn(false)

// here I'm setting up a mock that accepts any CreateBucketRequest
Mockito.when( mockedS3.createBucket(any(CreateBucketRequest.class)) )
    .thenReturn( mockBucket )

// execute the code under test
String result = doSomething()

// this is the line of the error where it doesn't see a call to createBucket 
// for any CreateBucketRequest
Mockito.verify( mockedS3 ).createBucket( any(CreateBucketRequest.class) )
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
amazonS3.createBucket(
  <any com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest>
);
-> at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3$createBucket$3.call(Unknown Source)

However, there were exactly 2 interactions with this mock:
amazonS3.doesBucketExistV2("bucket-1-pub");
-> at com.fuseanalytics.archiver.model.dao.AmazonFileDao.checkBucket(AmazonFileDao.java:142)

amazonS3.createBucket(
  com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest@255e5e2e
);
-> at com.fuseanalytics.archiver.model.dao.AmazonFileDao.checkBucket(AmazonFileDao.java:147)

Wanted but not invoked:
amazonS3.createBucket(
  <any com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest>
);
-> at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3$createBucket$3.call(Unknown Source)

However, there were exactly 2 interactions with this mock:
amazonS3.doesBucketExistV2("bucket-1-pub");
-> at com.fuseanalytics.archiver.model.dao.AmazonFileDao.checkBucket(AmazonFileDao.java:142)

amazonS3.createBucket(
  com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest@255e5e2e
);
-> at com.fuseanalytics.archiver.model.dao.AmazonFileDao.checkBucket(AmazonFileDao.java:147)
```

So from tracing out the call my `amazonS3.createBucket()` call is being called with a `CreateBucketRequest`, but instead of returning the `mockBucket` that I have configured.  It just returns null, then when I verify it was called that call doesn't match the conditions of verify and blamo exception city.

Update:  Things I've tried have been to move the `when()` calls so they align with the order in which the methods will be called in the code.  Didn't work.  (I glad that didn't work because how awful would that be?!  So much for black box testing right?)  I also tried to remove the `verify()` call for `createBucket()`.  That just resulted in the next verify (not pictured) to blow up because createBucket() still didn't return what I configured.

I can't see how this isn't working so I need some help to see my mistake.

Comment: It seems a bit strange to be using both `when` and `verify` on the same method of the same mock. I'm not sure it's a technical problem, but conceptually it's kind of weird

Comment: Can you post the code that instantiates the `mockedS3` variable.

Comment: doesBucketExistV2 and getName() are called before or after createBucket?

Comment: @stridecolossus I updated it,

Comment: @dreamcrash doesBucketExistV2 is called before createBucket, but Bucket.getName() is called after.

Comment: @Michael I sorta understand what you mean, but even if I don't have that verify there the next verify statement blows up too because createBucket() doesn't match the any() matcher and createBucket returns null when using this mock.

Comment: @chubbsondubs are you actually passing the mockedS3 as parameter to the class under test?

Comment: @dreamcrash Yes.  I am passing it into a setter like this `AmazonFileDao.setS3( mockedS3 )` I should add that I have 5 tests written and 3 of them pass while using Mockito.  I have 2 test that follow the above pattern and run into trouble with the any() matcher.

Comment: Sorry for the question, just want to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I left out an important detail my apologies to those who commented.  I'm writing my test with Groovy.  And it turns out it's Groovy's fault.  I started to suspect that Groovy was adding it's Groovy methods to Objects and that might make them appear not the same to Mockito.  So while it says it had an interaction with createBucket(CreateBucketRequest).  It wasn't recognizing CreateBucketRequest and CreateBucketRequest + Groovy Default Methods as the same thing when using any() matcher.

Now why this is happening is for the Mockito devs to figure out.  I suppose I should just go use Spock instead of junit, but that is for another day.  Thanks for the help.